# How to remove padding for display math equations when `org-export-preserve-breaks t`?

Tags: org-export, latex

When the variable `org-export-preserve-breaks` is `t`, the org contents...

```
text
\[
a + b + c
\]
text
```

gets exported to LaTeX as...

```
text\\[0pt]
\[
a + b + c
\]\\[0pt]
Text\\[0pt]
```

This adds a lot of extra padding to the equation in the pdf. Is there a way to avoid adding the latex-line-break-safe sequences to the exported LaTeX while keeping the variable set to `t`?

Answer (score 0):

Docstring of the user option `org-latex-line-break-safe` says that `[0pt]` protects the following `[...]` from being interpreted erroneously.

So, probably start with setting this user option value to an empty string, but watch out for possible errors.

```el
(setq org-latex-line-break-safe "")
```

If that doesn't work, read this [org mailing list discussion](https://list.orgmode.org/875ygk6a8z.fsf@posteo.net/) and then, if the issue still isn't resolved for you, `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: I think that would essentially be the same as setting `org-export-preserve-breaks` to `nil`. Would there be a way to define an export filter which targets these regions instead?